# Identity Framework UserLockoutEnabledByDefault works with oAuth Token

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to implement lockout feature in Identity Framework in my webapi. I'm using oAuth token https://myapi.com/Token
When a user authentication fails when logging in and getting a Token, it doesn't seem to affect the AccessFailedCount field in the database.  Googled and found that I need to use the SigninManager for the feature to work. Is there a way to implement it when issuing a Token?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly call [`AccessFailedAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151609(v=vs.108).aspx#M:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<code>2.AccessFailedAsync(</code>1)) on the `UserManager`:

```
if (userManager.SupportsUserLockout)
    await userManager.AccessFailedAsync(user);
```

For example, in an `OpenIdConnectServerProvider.HandleTokenRequest` context, this may look like:

```
var userManager =
    context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();

var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.Request.Username);

if (userManager.SupportsUserLockout && await userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user))
{
    context.Reject(
        error: OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
        description: "User locked out due to too many failed attempts. Try again later.");

    return;
}

if (!await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, context.Request.Password))
{
    // If lockout is supported, increment access failed count
    if (userManager.SupportsUserLockout)
        await userManager.AccessFailedAsync(user);

    context.Reject(
        error: OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
        description: "The username or password was invalid");

    return;
}
```